# Postgresql: Arrays instead of extra table in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, postgresql, many-to-many

I was wondering whether it is cleaner or faster using arrays of integers instead of creating an extra new table in a m-to-m relationship and using foreign keys to ensure data integrity.
What do you think? Do you say using arrays instead is a no-go?

Comment: The bridge table mechanism has been elaborated and optimized for decades. Just use it correctly. It is by far easier to query as well.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays to implement an m-to-n relationship are a no-go.

1. Write down the join between the two tables. You will notice that instead of two joins with an `=` as join condition, you now have a single join with `@>` as join condition (or a `LATERAL unnest` of the array, which is worse). That means that you are reduced to nested loop joins which will be slow if the tables are big (even if you create a GIN index to support the `@>`).
2. You cannot have referential integrity (foreign key constraints) that way.